# Linux Kernel Programming Book for 3.x versions

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm Trying to develop linux kernel module for my own server.
I have a Ubuntu with linux kernel 3.4, but I can't find any books or tutorials for developing modules on 3.x versions, all tutorials and books are for 2.x versions.

And the most part of code not compiling on 3.4 version, specially kernel threads parts.

Do you know anything that would be useful to understand 3.x module development ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not much difference between 2.6.32+ and 3.x in the basics how the kernel works. But yes, function names and APIs change from time to time. This is why books are already old once they are released. This is why I can recommend http://kernelnewbies.org/.

Similar questions have been answered already:

[Documentation about device driver programming on kernel 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582294/documentation-about-device-driver-programming-on-kernel-3-x)

[Linux Device Drivers 3rd Ed and 3.2 kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711444/linux-device-drivers-3rd-ed-and-3-2-kernel)

The best documentation is the Linux kernel source itself as it changes so quickly. There are a lot of comments in the code and you should really check out the "Documentation" directory.

Wouldn't it be a good exercise to port the examples to more recent versions?

Very important is a list of changes to keep up with the mainline development: http://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions

If they change the API, they also document the transition. Look at drivers doing similar things to what you want to achieve. How do they work? How did they react on API changes? ...

Subscribe to the related Linux kernel mailing lists and ask there for help for bigger issues from the active kernel developers.

Comment: Totally agree with Sebastian. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use LDD(Linux Device Driver) as reference but it's for 2.x kernel. you can join [Eudyptula Challenge](http://eudyptula-challenge.org/) challenge for kernel developing learning and training. also remember a very good reference always is [linux kernel source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux)